# Add Object in Object Array

Tags: arrays, object, mongoose, push

I try to add Object in Object Array (I use Mongoose).

My model:

```
let directoryCollection = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String },
    directory: [{
        name: { type: String },
        list: [ {type: Schema.ObjectId} ]
    }]
  },
  {collection: 'directory'}
);
```

I have an Array of ObjectID in my list.

My code to add Object in my Array Directory:

```
let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id);

directoryModel.update({
    'email': req.body.email,
}, {
    $push: { 'directory': {
        'name': req.body.directory,
        'list': [ { id } ]
    } 
}
}, function (req, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json('ok');
});
```

But the result is:

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

My variables are corrects.

An overview of my collection (with MongoDB Compass):

[image]

I think the syntax is not correct.
But I not able to find the correct syntax.

An idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Does the `list` part need `[{id}]` vs `[id]`? Just wondering ...

Comment: check your `email` ... try with putting hard coded value to the email